# Easiest way to prove integral of $e^{ikx}$ is $\delta(k)$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

What is the easiest way to to derive the following equation:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}dx = 2\pi\delta(k)$$

I understand the equation can be derived by assuming the Fourier integral theorem, but can anyone derive this without making reference to the Fourier integral theorem?

Comment: Please check this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/558077/is-there-any-handwavy-argument-that-shows-that-int-infty-infty-e-ikx/560206#560206

Comment: @Mathlover, thanks

Comment: @Mathlover, I struggle with the last part of that proof.  I can't understand the jump from lim sin(ax)/x = 2pidelta(k).  How can we prove the limit is 2pidelta(k)?

Comment: : It is just a defination : You could say $\lim\limits_{ a\to \infty  }  f_a(x) = \lim\limits_{ a\to \infty  } 2\frac{\sin {ax}}{x}= g(x)$ and you could try to draw $g(x)$. You can see some $a$ values how affect the graphs. You will get $g(x)$ as impulse graph if $a--->\infty$ . Then If you use Priyatham result in other question, you could see that
For $\epsilon>0$
$$ \int\limits_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon g(x) \mathrm{d}x = 2\pi$$


Finally 


Somebody defined that $g(x)=2\pi \delta(x)$. Is it ok now proof?

Comment: @Mathlover, I'm asking how do you know that the integral of g(x) from -e to e is 2pi. You've stated it but haven't proven it, and this is the only step in the proof I don't understand.

Comment: Please see other answer .As i wrote, Priyatham's answer gave that proof

Comment: see the answer here. I pretty much asked the same question not so long ago.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796744/the-delta-function-written-as-the-integral-of-a-complex-number

Comment: @markleeds, unfortunately that answer makes use of the fourier theorem, but I am trying to use the above integral to prove the fourier theorem.